# Detecting devices using react js

Tags: reactjs

I've been finished the web and mobile apps on my project. Now, I want to create a pop-up, if a user is using a web app instead of mobile on the mobile device, to tell him that I have a mobile app, and depending on OS to link him on google play or I store?

Answer (score 0):

you can check mobile or desktop using `navigator.userAgentData.mobile;`

to get platform details use

```
let platformDetails = await navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["architecture", "platform", "platformVersion", "model", "bitness", "uaFullVersion"]);
console.log(platformDetails);
```